# Find an invertible matrix $P$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $P^{−1}AP=D$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, random-matrices

Here is the question i took a picture of it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkpUG.png)

Comment: What is your question? What work have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in steps:

1. Using characteristic polynomials, show that $A$ has eigenvalues $-3,-2,2$.
2. Find the eigenvectors of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalues.
3. Set $P$ to be the matrix whose columns are eigenvectors of $A$. Set $D$ to have eigenvalues on its diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

Eigenvalue decomposition of $A$ is $PDP^{-1}$. 
$D$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal elements equal to the eigenvalues of $A$, and $P$ is the corresponding matrix whose clumns are the eigenvectors of $A$. The reason is that $$AP=PD$$ which results in $$A=PDP^{-1}$$

You can use it to get $$D=P^{-1}AP$$